# IsolatedStorageFileStream lead to assert failure

Tags: c#, windows-7, isolatedstoragefile

I decided to use isolated storage for temporary files:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream userStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("UserSettings.set", FileMode.Create, isoStore))
    {

    }
}
```

I taken this code from example *that works* on this computer. And minimal project with just this code also sucessfully runs.

But while performing `IsolatedStorageFileStream` constructor in my current project following message appears:

> MyApp.exe - Assert Failure
>
> Expression: [mscorlib recursive resource lookup bug]
>
> Desctiprion: Infinite recurion during resource lookup within mscorlib.
>   This may be a bug in mscorlib, or potentially in certain extensibility
>   points such as assembly resolve events or CultureInfo names.
>
> Resource name: Serurity_Generic

And in this message I can see pretty big stack trace (it starts with call of `IsolatedStorageFileStream` constructor):

[image]

Also I can't catch exception from this code.

Looks like error happened in `System.Environment.ResourceHelper.GetResourceStringCode()`.

What can be a possible reason for this? I can't find anything on this topic.

Deleting `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage` folder doesn't solve the problem (I know for sure that there is only my folders).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the stacktrace, the base issue comes from `LongPathFile.GetLength`. There could be some invalid characters in the path, or maybe a permission issue. Hard to tell without the exact error code.
Then, .NET tries to load the error message related to the error code, and at some point steps into `Costura.AssemblyLoader` (this must be your code or some library you're referencing). It looks like that AssemblyLoader subscribed to the `AssemblyResolve` event, and is doing a poor job fetching the correct assembly because it actually causes an infinite recursion.

In a nutshell: fix that assembly loader, then you'll be able to get the real error.

Comment: It does indeed look like a bug in the library: https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/138   From what I understand, when trying to resolve an assembly, it calls `GetName` on the referenced assemblies, which causes the referenced assembly to be loaded. So it goes back into the AssemblyResolve, then call GetName again, then goes back to AssemblyResolve, and so on.

Comment: You are right. I had to change current thread's culture to "en-US" to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case exactly this happened **on some of the machines** when my code tried to create a **new** file in `IsolatedStorage`. As correctly mentioned in [InfernumDeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3206223/infernumdeus)'s comment it happens only when the machine has non-English active locale set. Following code fixed the issue in my case:

```
var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
var currentUiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

var traceFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("system_log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentUiCulture;
```